# theme-settings.php not included in STARTER of foundation subtheme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, zurb-foundation, drupal-theming

I'm trying to create a subtheme of the foundation theme so I'm following the directions in the readme in starter map. All goes well except for there isn't a theme-settings.php file included in the starter map. I've now just copied the theme-settings.php file from the base foundation theme. Will this give me setbacks in the future? Do I need to create my own theme-settings.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do fine without a `theme-settings.php` in your subtheme, unless you need to customize the theme settings form. I noticed the entry in the README file too, and I think it refers either to a previous version of the Foundation theme or to a next proposed feature.

If you don't need to customize your subtheme settings form you can happily proceed. If you do - or will in the future-, you can provide your own  theme-settings.php; just be aware of issue [#943212](https://drupal.org/node/943212) in Drupal queue. You can find a neat workaround to that issue in Zen theme starterkit's `theme-settings.php`.